# How to push notification on android device in node js using GCM?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-messaging

I want to push notification in android devices through node js using node

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way is to use Firebase Cloud Message (FCM), you can send notifications to your Android and iOS devices over an fcm_token provided by Firebase SDK. They provide a super easy node js SDK. It's Google solution and simple to use.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?refresh=1

If you dont like Google, this is an other 100% free option that allow you to do the same job, One Signal.

https://onesignal.com/